# Understanding Git for Visual Studio 2015: Revert

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

For a test I have a simple console app and I commit it (Initial). Then I add a comment and commit it (00). Then I change the comment and commit it (01)

Now I want to simply revert back to 00.

```
Changes | Actions | View History
right-click 00 | Revert
Are you sure you want to revert .... | Yes
```

At this point I get a conflict: *Program.cs [both modified]*. But why would that be a conflict -- I just want to revert to the previous version?. I click that and then I have options to:

```
Merge (button)
Edited on Source | Diff | Take Source (links)
Edited on Target | Diff | Take Source (links)
```

If I click *Merge* I see three different panes, all with different versions (source, target, and merge).

The source looks like my first version (initial), the target looks like my current version (01) and the merge looks like what I have chosen to to revert to (00).

If I close that window I get a dialog that asks if I want to accept the merge results -- and from there I am able to do the revert with the merged document.

Can you explain what is meant by the source and target panels (it seems like the target is my current version, but the source looks like a version even before this reversion that I want (it looks like initial!).

Ultimately I can keep the source panel, the target panel or the results of the merge, essentially reverting to any of those three choices. Is this the way the VS 2015 tool is intended to work? Key question: what if I just want to revert to the previous version's file completely without any merging?

Also... I noticed when I watched the Microsoft Build Demo on this tool they did a revert and did not have the problem I discussed above. https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-746 (see at the 7:30 mark).

Thank you!

p.s. I did not find documentation for how revert works for this tool on the Internet so if there is one please point that link and I will look there :)

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what you do, but if you have two commits in your history, and you right-click the first commit and choose revert for it, then you are not *reverting back* to that version, but you essentially want to *undo* that version. So you want to keep the change in commit 01 but undo the change in 00. Assuming that 00 added the `Program.cs` and 01 modified it, undoing 00 will of course cause problems because you are asking to remove it again although you have changed it since in 01.

Comment: I have 3 commits: Initial (add Program.cs), then 00 (add a comment), then 01 (change the comment). Now I just want to revert from where I currently am back to 00.

Comment: Then you want to *revert* change 01.

Comment: Ahh now I see my error... I thought in History you selected the one you want to **revert to** but I see from your comment you select the one that you want to be **reverted**!

Comment: `git revert` for VS 2015 is the same as `git revert` anywhere else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you select a commit to revert, Visual Studio does not "revert to" that point in time - it does a logical removal of the changes that commit introduced.  It attempts to remove only the changes that were introduced in that commit.

Consider some series of commits for a single file:

### Commit 1

```
Line one
Line two
Line three
Line four
Line five
```

### Commit 2

```
Line one
Line 2
Line three
Line 4
Line five
```

### Commit 3

```
Line ONE
Line 2
Line three
Line 4
Line FIVE
```

If you want to revert commit 2 - you are trying to undo the changes that it introduced, while retaining the changes introduced in commit 3.  The results will be:

### Reverted Commit 2

```
Line ONE
Line two
Line three
Line four
Line FIVE
```

However, there can be conflicts.  If commit 2 had changed the same line that commit 3 had changed, the revert would fail with a conflict, and you would have to resolve it to continue.