# Why do I run into git merge conflicts when I do a revert?

Tags: git, github

So I've been trying to revert to the a prior version of my project. But I keep getting merge conflicts when I do a git revert. Why on earth does this make sense? I'm saying "I want to revert to this prior version, exactly as it was then" and now it's saying I need to keep some of the current code. No, I want none of it, I screwed up my project somehow and think this earlier version wasn't screwed up. I know I should just be able to resolve these problems, but I've never done a massive merge conflict before, and I don't understand a lot of this Xcode code.

Also, if I revert a commit, do I go BEFORE or AFTER the commit? For instance...

Commit A, Commit B, Commit C, Commit D.

I revert Commit B. Where do I go? After A, or after B?

```
$ git revert 8873550de2b6c4bec42cfec4e98600736f01ffb9
error: could not revert 8873550... Grid view
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

Comment: `git revert` != `git checkout`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358035/whats-the-difference-between-git-revert-checkout-and-reset

Comment: ... or see [Chris's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34978213/2541573) below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Git for Visual Studio 2015: Revert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222674/understanding-git-for-visual-studio-2015-revert)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm saying "I want to revert to this prior version, exactly as it was then"

Actually, [you're not](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert):

> Given one or more existing commits, revert the changes that the related patches introduce, and record some new commits that record them.

Given this simple history

```
D [master]
|
C
|
B
|
A
```

`git revert B` generates a new commit on top of `D` that reverses the changes introduced in `B` (see the example below). If the changes introduced in `C` conflict with this new commit, you'll get conflicts.

> if I revert a commit, do I go BEFORE or AFTER the commit

Neither. You'd end up with something like

```
E [master]
|
D
|
C
|
B
|
A
```

where `E`'s changes reverse `C`'s changes.

If you want to "go back in time" to `B` you can use `git checkout B` (which will result in a [detached head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-my-git-repo-enter-a-detached-head-state), which generally isn't helpful if you want to make new changes from that point), you can use `git reset` to move `master` back to `B`, making `C` and `D` eligible for garbage collection, or you can use `git branch` to create a *new* branch at `B`.

With the information in your question I can't tell which of these you want.